# express/connect middleware which executes after the response is sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, node.js-connect

Is it possible to write a middleware which executes after the response is sent to a client or after the request is processed and called just before sending the response to client?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pauljz gave the basic method but to expand on that here is an example of middleware

```
module.exports = function() {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    req.on("end", function() {
      // some code to be executed after another middleware
      // does some stuff
    });
    next(); // move onto next middleware
  }
}
```

In your main app

```
expressApp.use(require("./doneMiddleware"));
expressApp.use(express.logger());
expressApp.use(express.static.....
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this event will trigger when the client completes sending request/data to server. But what I want is, after calling response.render or response.redirect etc, the middle ware should be executed.

Comment: No, this event is emitted once the entire request is done, including sending the response. So long as render/redirect call response.end the associated request will emit end.

Comment: @SelvarajMA 
The following approach may be better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21858212/673014.

Answer (score 4):

See if binding to `req.on('end', function() {...});` will work for you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this event will trigger when the client completes sending request/data to server. But what I want is, after calling response.render or response.redirect etc, the middle ware should be executed.