# How do I write a Plack middleware that runs after the HTTP response is sent to the client?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, middleware, deferred-execution, plack

My Plack web service logs via a TCP connection to fluentD, and I'd like to execute my logging code *after* I've sent the response back to the client.  This would reduce response time (assume this is a high request volume service where such a performance optimization is worth doing).

At least one other web framework, express for nodejs, supports this by enabling middlewares to add an [on-end event handler to the request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761814/express-connect-middleware-which-executes-after-the-response-is-sent-to-the-clie).
I've looked at the [Plack::Request](http://p3rl.org/Plack::Request) and [Plack::Response](http://p3rl.org/Plack::Response) interfaces, and I didn't see a similar event hook.

I think I could probably do a local override of the [finalize](http://p3rl.org/Plack::Response#finalize) method in my middleware to force the framework to do my logging after the response is finalized, but I'd like to avoid tinkering with the Plack internals if possible.

Is there a better way to defer execution of some code until after a response has been sent to the client?

Comment: all the code on your web server can be divided into two parts: servicing the response and related work. usually having queue service for related work is the best solution. so... why you don't want to add a queue?

Comment: you can use hooks, after sending response you can do your background process in another hook by simply calling next() in your function.

Comment: The event hook is optional in Plack because the base implementation must be abstract enough to run on many types of servers. Use `Plack::Handler::Net::Async::HTTP::Server` to expose `$env->{'io.async.loop'}`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [LeoNerd](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1069726) and ilmari for their debugging help in [MagNET](http://irc.perl.org) `#io-async`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S plackup -s Net::Async::HTTP::Server
use Future::AsyncAwait;
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use Future::IO qw();
use Future::IO::Impl::IOAsync qw();

async sub mylogger {
    # simulate expensive run-time
    await Future::IO->sleep(1);
    open my $log, '>>', '/tmp/so-58605156.log';
    $log->say(time);
}

my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    mylogger->retain;
    return [200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [time]];
};
```

Comment: I see your running plack with a Net::Async::HTTP::Server server.  Is it not possible to do do logging post-response in a pre-fork server like Starman?

Comment: Many more possibilities: 1. Employ a simple process fork and pipe loglines into it, e.g. [Proc::Fork](http://p3rl.org/Proc::Fork). 2. Put the logger code into an external logger program; spawn it as background process when needed. 3. Use a job queue, e.g. [Minion](http://p3rl.org/Minion).